# Select rows in pandas datafame that satisfy a condition in a column that depends on a subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas, filter

give the following dataframe I would like to select the rows for each user that has the highest amount:

```
Name     Amount   ID
--------------------
Alice       100   1
Bob          50   2
Charlie      10   3
Alice        30   4
Charlie      50   5
```

the result should be:

```
Name     Amount   ID
--------------------
Alice       100   1
Bob          50   2
Charlie      50   5
```

how can i do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['Amount'].idxmax()]
```

output:

```
      Name  Amount  ID
0    Alice     100   1
1      Bob      50   2
4  Charlie      50   5
```

If you want to reset_index(), then just add it at the end like:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['Amount'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
      Name  Amount  ID
0    Alice     100   1
1      Bob      50   2
2  Charlie      50   5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby.apply`:

```
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Amount'].eq(x['Amount'].max())]).reset_index(drop=True)
```